# How add Gridview Column Values

Tags: gridview

I have Three columns in gridview like this:

Exam Attendance Internal Total

45 (textbox) 5(textbox) 50(textbox) 95(textbox)

Here Exam ,Attendance,Internal are entry ,

I want Total will calculate auotmatically using javascript after Click event fired from internal

Comment: and you are using what language/toolkit/framework ?

Answer (score 0):

decalre a variable total, loop through each cell of the row and add to total. do with total as you desire